# Durga devi associated with Anthills

Tags: devi, durga

In South India, I have visited many Devi(amman) temples which are associated with Anthills like the Putlur Amman temple - The suburb is famous for the temple dedicated to Goddess Angala Parameswari (Goddess Parvathy, Goddess Poongavanathu Amman), Mariamman is often associated with Anthills (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariamman). Why is Devi(amman) associated with anthills?